# "and" with meals - eating separately or together

Tags: conjunctions

> I have toast **and** jam for breakfast.

Does it mean that I eat toast and jam **separately** or **together** with spread jam on toast?

What about other examples? Does "and" mean separately or together as if combined?

> I have cereal **and** milk for for breakfast.
>
> I have fish **and** potatoes for dinner.

**Edit: I've edited some examples and added new. I need some clarification.**

What about bread and butter?

> I have bread **and** butter for breakfast.

or

> I have pastries **and** milk.

Does it mean here mixed or separate? I mean I first eat pastries, then milk or eat them together?

Can I replace "and" with "with" without a difference in meaning?

Comment: It could mean either; which one is context dependent. Though if eaten together, I would use *with* in place of *and*: "I will have cereal *with* milk.". Also, just using *have* indicates they are in your possession, not that you are eating them.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking: `and` doesn't mean mixing them up together. It only means `as well` or `in addition to`. For example, I can say:

> Yesterday I ate some fruits and vegetables.

It doesn't even mean that I ate them in the same meal, let alone being mixed together. It only means that I ate both.

Although depending on the context it may mean mixing up together, but to make sure you had them together in a single sentence, you may say:

> I have toast ***with*** jam.
>
> I'm having fish ***along with*** potatoes.

Comment: Thank you. What about my other examples? I've added more examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is much more about common sense than about grammar.  If I say I'm having *toast and jam*, you naturally assume the jam is spread on the toast, because that is common practice.  In the same way, *tea and biscuits* is separate, because that's how most people consume them.

Unless you're completely unfamiliar with the food mentioned, just use your best judgement.  Otherwise you have to ask.  For example if say in Japan they have a dish called "Ochazuke" which is *tea and rice* (and other things), you might have to ask for details or look it up on Google.

([FYI it's like a soup of green tea over rice](http://www.cookforyourlife.org/recipes/green-tea-over-rice-ochazuke/).  Very nice, especially in cold weather.)

Comment: "tea and biscuits" actually are together for many people, because they dunk their biscuits in their tea before eating them. It's so prevalent a practice that I would hesitate to suggest that "most" people consume them separately -- at least, when discussing the habits of the inhabitants of the British Isles.